# JWT Token not sent to allowedDomain or whitelistedDomains in auth0/angular-jwt when using Regexp config

Tags: angular, jwt

I am using [auth0/angular-jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@auth0/angular-jwt) library for injecting the JWT token in my app. In the library docs it states that configuracion can be done by strings or RegExp for setting the allowed domains. But, when using the following configuration in the app.module.ts import section

```
 JwtModule.forRoot({
  config: {
    tokenGetter: tokenGetter,
    whitelistedDomains:[new RegExp("([a-z]+)*-api[.]mydomain[.]cl"),new RegExp("localhost[:]8080")]
  }
}),
```

The main.js file compiled for production gets {tokenGetter:r,whitelistedDomains:[]} and thus, no token is injected as there is no allowed domain.

If using strings as domains it works fine. When compiling this

```
JwtModule.forRoot({
  config: {
    tokenGetter: tokenGetter,
    whitelistedDomains:["demo-api.mydomain.cl"),"localhost:8080"]
  }
}),
```

The main.js is correctly configured {tokenGetter:r,whitelistedDomains:["localhost:8080","demo-api.tumunicipio.cl"]}

package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "8.2.2",
"@angular/common": "8.2.2",
"@angular/compiler": "8.2.2",
"@angular/core": "8.2.2",
"@angular/forms": "8.2.2",
"@angular/platform-browser": "8.2.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.2.2",
"@angular/platform-server": "8.2.2",
"@angular/router": "8.2.2",
"@auth0/angular-jwt": "^4.2.0",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a problem with the [AOT compilation](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#expression-syntax). Here is an [angular issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13702) on the topic. The only solutions avaliable are:

- Disable aot for compiling. Not recomendend.
- Use strings in the allowed domains for JwtModule.